# When I try and execute code on Geany the error message is - the system cannot find the path specified

Tags: python, settings, geany

I am new to coding and have just downloaded python and Geany geany-1.34.1_setup.exe. onto windows 10. I saved an empty file hello_world.py. and entered print("Hello Python World") into the editing window.  The error is the system cannot find the path specified.  I then went into the build commands and changed the Compile command to C:\Python35\python -m py_compile "%f" and the Execute command to C:\Python35\python "%f" but am still getting the same error message. Im not sure what I need to do to fix this.

capture of code and result
[image]

geany build configurations - first half of python commands
[image]

second half of python command in build configurations
[image]

Comment: This look like a path problem, not geany's. Can you post exactly the code and the response, use backticks (`) to format text as code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I have edited the original question to have a screenshot of my code and the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Geany [Build configuration](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#execute) to adjust the path and which version of python is launched.

> Execute will run the corresponding executable file, shell script or interpreted script in a terminal window. The command set in the "Set Build Commands" dialog is run in a script to ensure the terminal stays open after execution completes.

Comment: I cannot seem to work out what to put in the build commands, I have edited the main post again with two screen shots of my current commands. the python I have installed is python 3.7

Comment: The path problem for script execution is here : https://framapic.org/zoWlxZkiFz1j/VkzTZjbOT2Gp.png
I never used windoz, so I cannot tell you the good path to use… I imagine that it was `C:\Python3.7(…)`, put here the command you need to execute in Windoz command line

Answer (score 0):

-install python in your windows

-set path variables(you can do this at the time of installation.since,python installer have a check box to add path at it's first page)

-open and compile the program from geany
-if it shows "the system cannot find the file specified", try running the geany as  an administrator